# loading encrypted shared objects using the rtld / free loader/linkers

Tags: c, linux, elf

I am doing some research in encryption/software protection. I want to link dynamically encrypted shared objects (Linux, x86 Architecture, ELF32/64 format)

- The code to be protected is contained (encrypted, no valid ELF) in the shared object.
- The object itself is a valid ELF-file, containing an init method
- The decryption should be started, dependend on a available license in the init function called by the loader.
- After encryption the code is present as valid ELF-file in memory.

There were some further requirements:

- The decrypted code must not be stored (even temporarily on disk) - prevent easy object dump and code reuse
- The protection algorithm must not be published, so I may not use parts of the GNU code (even people do a great work there!)

I think the hard way is to reimplement a loader/linker providing the needed functionality... Perhaps there may be a way to use the Linux rtld, or parts of it, other linkers? 
Is there an easier way?
Thanks for every idea/hint

Some related links/Infos

- a packer solving a similar kind of problem: http://www.upx.org/
  (did not work for one of my test shared objects)
- Some details about loading shared objects http://smilax.org/135/dsohowto.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Shiva](http://www.securereality.com.au/) if you're interested in this. There was no source code released to the public but the theory is still there.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, [Phrack](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=58&id=5#article) featured an article on ELF encryption. Also a long time go, there was a program called BurnEye to encrypt ELF binaries.

Comment: I was told that there also exists a tool called burndump available at [link](http://www.securiteam.com) stripping the protection...